# rails devise に関する質問

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

rails でウェブアプリを作成しているところです。

deviseの導入→独自カラムの追加→ユーザーによる情報の変更（マイページのような）→ユーザー名でのログインなど初心者なりに取り組んでいたのですが、、、

いざ、最初から実際に動くか確認していたところ、すでに作成済みのユーザーに関しては問題ないのですが、新規登録をしようと試みると、
**Email can't be blank**
というエラーが返ってきます。もちろん空で登録しようとしたわけではありません。

色々と取り組むうちに何が影響しているのかわからなくなってしまいました。
どなたかお助けください！

[image: user model]

[image: コントローラー]

Answer (score 0):

`sign_in`の時しか許可されてないので`sign_up`のときにも許可するようにしたら直ると思います。

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  # ...
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :name, :email])
end
```

質問する際はコードを画像じゃなくてテキストでお願いします。
回答者が修正する時に手打ちする事になりますし検索性も下がりますので。